# How to encode data to remove any 0x00 bytes

Tags: encoding

I am streaming some data of fixed length. The data consists of some 64-bit ints as well as some 32-bit floats. Because the format of the data is fixed and known, I am just sending an array of bytes with a known endian-ness. The data can then be easily reconstructed at the other end.

However, my transport protocol will not allow any 0x00 bytes. Is there a way I can encode my data differently to avoid this? Losing some range in the data is fine (e.g. ints having a maximum of 2^60 is totally fine). Incresing the full size of the message is totally fine too, as long as the full length of data is fixed no matter what the values of the ints and floats are (e.g. if ints now take 9 bytes to store).

I don't know much about encoding formats, but I learned about CRCs a long time ago and I'm wondering if there's something like that, which will add some fixed length block to the end of the bytestream, but which will prevent the bytestream from containing any 0x00 bytes?

Comment: For 64 bit numbers there is a fairly trivial approach where you could use 56 bits for the value, replace all the 0x00 bytes with 0xff bytes, and use the leftover byte to record the byte positions that you replaced.

Comment: Oh thanks, that seems promising! However in the case that the value contains no 0x00 bytes, then the leftover byte would be 0x00! But I think this approach is heading in the right direction

Comment: No, it would not. Because you have one leftover bit in that byte that you can always set to  1. You only need 7 bits to encode the switches for the 7 remaining bytes.

Comment: Oh of course! yup, this seems like the perfect solution thanks so much! And thanks for the fast response

Comment: I'll write it up as an answer?

Comment: Sure, if you would then I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the case of 64-bit numbers:

1. Reduce your value range to 2<sup>56</sup> and use the last (or first) 7 bytes to encode that value.
2. For the 7 value bytes, replace all the `0x00` bytes with `0xff` bytes. Record the positions of the bytes that have been flipped.
3. Use the remaining byte as a bit mask to encode the positions of the bytes that have been flipped. This will take up 7 bits of that remaining byte. The first (or last) bit of that byte needs to be always set to `1` to prevent the encoding byte to become `0x00` itself.

For example:

1. Take the 7 byte value `b2 00 c3 d4 e5 ff 00`.
2. Flip the `0x00` bytes to get `b2 ff c3 d4 e5 ff ff`. Bytes 2 and 7 have been flipped.
3. Create the bit mask `0100001` and prefix with a `1` bit to get a binary value of `10100001`, or a hex value of `0xa1`.
   Your encoded 64-bit value will then be `a1 b2 ff c3 d4 e5 ff ff`.

The approach for 32-bit numbers is the same. Use 28 bits for the value, 3 bits to encode which bytes have been flipped, and the leftover bit always set to 1.